# Pass form variables to php. Prevent page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am working on a web site which displays some data that is retrieved from a database using php. Now, there are also other chekcboxes, which are included in a form. Based on the user input on these checkboxes, i wanted the div displaying the data to reload. For example, after a user checks one of the boxes and clicks apply, the div displaying should recompute the results. I realise that the form data must be passed onto an ajax function. Which would convert this form data into a json object and send it across to a php file. The php file can then access the form variables using $_POST['var']. I hope i have got the theory correct. Nevertheless, i have a number of problems during execution.

Firstly, the php code that deals with the form variables in on the same page as the form. I want to know how to direct the form data from the ajax function to this code.

Secondly, the ajax function is getting executed alright, the form is getting submitted, the page isn't reloading (as desired) but however, I am not able to access the submitted variables in the php code.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $('#filter_form').on('submit', function (e) {
          $.ajax({
            type:   'post',
            url:    'index.php',
            data:   $('#filter_form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });
          e.preventDefault();
        });
      });
    </script>
<div style="float: left;margin-left: -175px;" class="box2">
        <h2>Filter by :</h2>
        <form id="filter_form" name="filter_form" href="#">
        <!--<form id="filter_form" name="filter_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method ="post" href="#">-->
        <h3>Location</h3>
        <?php
            //Get all the distinct values for filter. For example, Get all the locations available, display them in a container. Similarly for the party type as well. Connect to to the database once, get all these values,
            //store them in arrays and use the arrays to display on screen.
            $query = "Select LOCATION, PARTY_TYPE, GENRE, HAPPY_HOURS, OUTDOOR_ROOFTOP from venue_list order by HAPPY_HOURS";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            $filter_array = array(5);
            for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
                $filter_array[$i] = array();
            }
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                array_push($filter_array[0],$row['LOCATION']);
                array_push($filter_array[1],$row['PARTY_TYPE']);
                array_push($filter_array[2],$row['GENRE']);
                array_push($filter_array[3],$row['HAPPY_HOURS']);
                array_push($filter_array[4],$row['OUTDOOR_ROOFTOP']);
            }
            for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
                $filter_array[$i] = array_unique($filter_array[$i]);
            }   
            ?>
            <ul>
            <?php
                foreach($filter_array[0] as $location){
                ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="f1" name="location[]" value="<?php echo $location?>" <?php if (isset($_POST['location'])){echo (in_array($location,$_POST['location']) ? 'checked' : '');}?>/>
                    <label for="f1"><?php echo $location?></label>
                </li>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
        <br>
        <h3>Party Type</h3>
            <ul>
            <?php
                foreach($filter_array[1] as $party_type){
                ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="f2" name="party_type[]" value="<?php echo $party_type?>" <?php if (isset($_POST['party_type'])){echo (in_array($party_type,$_POST['party_type']) ? 'checked' : '');}?>/>
                    <label for="f2"><?php echo $party_type?></label>
                </li>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
        <br><h3>Genre</h3>
            <ul>
            <?php
                foreach($filter_array[2] as $genre){
                ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="f3" name="genre[]" value="<?php echo $genre?>" <?php if (isset($_POST['genre'])){echo (in_array($genre,$_POST['genre']) ? 'checked' : '');}?>/>
                    <label for="f3"><?php echo $genre?></label>
                </li>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
        <br>
        <h3>Happy Hours</h3>
            <ul>
            <?php
                foreach($filter_array[3] as $happy_hours){
                ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="f4" name="happy_hours[]" value="<?php if($happy_hours){ echo $happy_hours;} else {echo "Dont Bother";} ?>" <?php if (isset($_POST['happy_hours'])){echo (in_array($happy_hours,$_POST['happy_hours']) ? 'checked' : '');}?>/>
                    <label for="f4"><?php echo $happy_hours?></label>
                </li>
                <?php
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
        <br>
        <h3>Outdoor/Rooftop</h3>
            <ul>
            <?php
                foreach($filter_array[4] as $outdoor_rooftop){
                ?>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="f5" name="outdoor_rooftop[]" value="<?php echo $outdoor_rooftop?>" <?php if (isset($_POST['outdoor_rooftop'])){echo (in_array($location,$_POST['outdoor_rooftop']) ? 'checked' : '');}?>/>
                    <label for="f5"><?php echo $outdoor_rooftop?></label>
                </li>
                <?php
                $i=$i+1;
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
            <br><br><br>
            <div id="ContactForm" action="#">
                <input name="filter_button" type="submit"  value="Apply"  id="filter_button"  class="button"/>
            </div>
    <!--
        <h2>Sort by :</h2>
        <input type="radio" id="s1" name="sort" value="Name" <?php if (isset($_POST['sort'])){echo ($_POST['sort'] == 'Name')?'checked':'';}?>/>
        <label for="f1"><?php echo 'Name'?></label>
        <input type="radio" id="s1" name="sort" value="Location" <?php if (isset($_POST['sort'])){echo ($_POST['sort'] == 'Location')?'checked':'';}?>/>
        <label for="f1"><?php echo 'Location'?></label>
        <br><br><br>
        <input name="filter_button" type="submit"  value="Apply"  id="filter_button"  class="button"/>
    -->
        </form>
    </div>
<div class="wrapper">
            <h2>Venues</h2>
            <br>
            <div class="clist" id="clublist" href="#">
                <?php
                    ?>
                    <table id = "venue_list">
                    <tbody>
                    <?php

                    //Functions
                    //This function builds the query as every filter attribute is passed onto it.
                    function query_builder($var_name){
                        $append = strtoupper($var_name)." in (";
                        $i=0;
                        foreach($_POST[$var_name] as $array){
                            $append = $append."'{$array}'";
                            $i=$i+1;
                            if($i < count($_POST[$var_name])){
                                $append = $append.",";
                            }
                            else{
                                $append=$append.")";
                            }
                        }
                        return $append;
                    }

                    //We first need to check if the filter was set in the previous page. If yes, then the query needs to be built with a 'where'. If not the query will just display all values.
                    //We also need to check if order by is required. If yes, we will apply the corresponding sort, else we will just sort on the basis of location.
                    //The below 2 variables do the same.
                    $filter_set = 0;
                    $filter_variables = array('location','party_type','genre','happy_hours','outdoor_rooftop');
                    $map_array = array();

                    if(isset($_POST['location'])){
                        $filter_set = 1;
                    }
                    if(isset($_POST['party_type'])){
                        $filter_set = 1;
                    }
                    if(isset($_POST['genre'])){
                        $filter_set = 1;
                    }
                    if(isset($_POST['happy_hours'])){
                        $filter_set = 1;
                    }
                    if(isset($_POST['outdoor_rooftop'])){
                        $filter_set = 1;
                    }

                    if($filter_set == 1){
                        $query = "Select * from venue_list where ";
                        $append_query=array(5);
                        $j=0;

                        foreach($filter_variables as $var){
                            if(isset($_POST[$var])){
                                $append_query[$j] = query_builder($var);
                                $j=$j+1;
                            }
                        }

                        $h=0;
                        //Once all the individual where clauses are built, they are appended to the main query. Until then, they are stored in an array from which they are
                        //sequentially accessed.
                        foreach($append_query as $append){
                            $query=$query.$append;
                            $h=$h+1;
                            if($h < $j){
                                $query=$query." AND ";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        $query = "Select * from venue_list";
                    }

                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        $name = $row['NAME'];
                        $img = $row['IMAGE_SRC'];
                        $addr = $row['ADDRESS'];
                        $location = $row['LOCATION'];

                        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>map_function('{$addr}','{$name}','{$img}');</script>";
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $img.".jpg"?>" height="100" width="100">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    <?php echo $name?>
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:none;">
                                    <?php echo $location?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>                       
                    <?php
                    }
                ?>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
            </div>
          <br>
       </div>
```

All the 3 components are part of index.php. Kindly notify me if the code is unreadable or inconvenient I will edit it. Awaiting a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to add `return false;` ?

Comment: Yes I did. Still doesn't seem to work. :(

Comment: try my answer should work

Answer (score 0):

in this case change your javascript code to

```
var submiting = false;

    function submitmyforum()
    {

        if ( submiting == false )
       {

          submiting  = true;

           $.ajax({
                type:   'post',
                url:    'index.php',
                data:   $('#filter_form').serialize(),
                success: function () {
                  alert('form was submitted');
                  submiting  = false;
                }
              });
      }else
       {
       alert("Still working ..");
       }
     }
```

and change the form submit button to

```
 <input name="filter_button" type="button" onclick="submitmyforum();"  value="Apply"  id="filter_button"  class="button"/>
```

don't forget to change submit button `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Comment: I tried the above code. The alert('Form was submitted') is getting displayed alright but there is no change in the contents of the div. Is there anything wrong in the way I'm accessing the post variables through php?

Comment: try to add `alert( $('#filter_form').serialize());` inside the function did you see correct submitted values ?

Comment: Yes the values are correct. I believe there is something wrong with the way php is receiving it. Any ideas on that?

Comment: correct you need to set this answer as solved and ask another one for your php problem and we shall assist you :)

Comment: Where do you handle the POST response data?

`success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
$('#clublist').html($(data).filter('#clublist').contents());
}`

BTW, remember to inspect the request sent and the response you get (instead of spawning alerts and adding debug handlers). Even IE8 DevTools implement this quite well. You can see there what was sent and what you got.

Comment: Hi Zamber, can you please explain your comment? :) I am relatively new to php and web development.

Comment: From the beginning. The user loads the page. Initially no filters are applied. Then you set some filters and do an AJAX POST request to the same page. If the user has JS disabled he will normally get the refreshed page with filters applied, but instead we use JS to get the filtered data and substitute it on the current page (getting rid of that pesky refresh). After the request is done the `success` handler function is called with the data of the request (the whole page as it would go in the no-JS case). There you have to put the data somewhere for the user to see the changes hence the .html()

Comment: Okay. So on success, passes $data to clublist? Is that what it is doing?

Comment: `$('#clublist')` gets the #clublist on the page `.html(` changes the html contents of the selected element `$(data)` parses the response data to a jQuery object `.filter('#clublist')` filters it for the #clublist element `.contents()` takes the contents of it `)` ends the opening parentheses of .html(. So essentially yes, it passes the data to #clublist :).

Comment: Okay. I get it now, the response will be an entire html page, which needs to be filtered and send across to the corresponding div. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49470/discussion-between-jones-and-zamber)